# Dailymotion api showing error with http protocol

Tags: api, http, https, dm, dailymotion-api

I am trying to get the dailymotion video details with the following link using file_get_contents method i.e  http://api.dailymotion.com/video/x1ckrm4. But here I am getting "403 Forbidden URL [2]" error but when I use https protocol, I am getting video details. Can any one tell me why it is so?

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is from Dailymotion API, which is using HTTPS, this is why you can't get it over HTTP !

Have a look at http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html to see how it works.